# Mysql Join Multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to join 5 different tables. They each have a

Name column, Id Column and Exp column

Other than that, there is nothing completely the same about all of them.

```
SELECT name FROM `weapons`,`arrows`,`trees`,`ores`,`bars` ORDER BY exp DESC
```

Is all I can come up with, which it says Name is ambiguous. Thanks!

**This is like 5 separate user tables that I'm trying to combine into one big list**

Comment: Are you sure you're not wanting a UNION instead of a JOIN?

Comment: I have no idea what I need. hah....

Comment: @AlanBowen please post some sample data and then the desired result, then you will get an answer that can produce the result.

Comment: Okay, based on the edit that you want one bit list, you're wanting to UNION the tables, not JOIN, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use one table prefix to identify the table from which,  you want to retrieve `name` e.g. below:

```
 SELECT w.name FROM weapons w, arrows a, trees t, ores o, bars b ORDER BY exp DESC
```

**I think you are missing the join conditions as well.**

Your query should look like:

```
SELECT w.name 
FROM weapons w JOIN arrows a
     ON w.id = a.id
     JOIN trees t
     ON a.id = t.id
     JOIN ores o 
     ON t.id = o.id
     JOIN  bars b 
     ON o.id = b.id
ORDER BY exp DESC;
```

Or if you want to to a `union --> combine rows from all tables` then :

```
 SELECT name 
 FROM weapons 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT name 
 FROM arrows
 UNION ALL
 SELECT name 
 FROM trees
 UNION ALL
 SELECT name 
 FROM ores
 UNION ALL
 SELECT name 
 FROM bars;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have columns with the same name you need to add the table name to the column. You can also use an alias name for a table and shorten your query.

If you want to select the `name` column of the `weapons` and `arrows` table do

```
SELECT w.name, a.name
FROM `weapons` as w, `arrows` as a,`trees` as t,`ores` ass o,`bars` as b
ORDER BY exp DESC
```

Comment: None of the tables have the same names.

Comment: I would place an alias on the column names so you know what table it comes from `weapons.name as WeaponsName, arrows.name as ArrowsName`

Comment: @AlanBowen: But the columns have same names. You need to tell the DB engine which `name` column you want from which table.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for one big list, you want to UNION the tables, not JOIN.

```
SELECT * FROM weapons
UNION
SELECT * FROM arrows
UNION 
SELECT * FROM trees
UNION 
SELECT * FROM ores
UNION
SELECT * FROM bars;
```

And if you just want the names, `SELECT name` instead of `SELECT *`

Answer (score 0):

If you want one large list, you can use the following:

```
select name, id, exp, 'weapons' as TableFrom
from weapons
union all
select name, id, exp, 'arrows' as TableFrom
from arrows
union all
select name, id, exp, 'trees' as TableFrom
from trees
union all
select name, id, exp, 'ores' as TableFrom
from ores
union all
select name, id, exp, 'bars' as TableFrom
from bars
order by 3
```

I added a final column to help identify what table the data is coming from. If you don't want that, then you can drop it.